# KSH Shell script Matching file pattern

Tags: shell, ksh

I am new to shell script. I want to iterate a directory for the below specific pattern.

```
Ad_sf_03041500000.dat
SF_AD_0304150.DEL
SF_AD_0404141.EXP
```

Number of digits should be exactly match with this pattern.
I am using KSH shell script. Could you please help me to iterate only those files in for loop.

Comment: Could you please do let me know which pattern should match with file names? What should be expected output? Do you want specific files in a directory or you want to look all the files?

Comment: Your say "*Number of digits should be exactly match with this pattern*", but the number of digits is different for your first example to your second and third.  Please describe *exactly* how many alpha, how many numerics, and which "extensions" are valid.  How about case, is that significant?

Comment: Thanks for your support my friends. my file pattern is ad_sf_11digits.dat and SF_AD_7digits.EXP and SF_AD_7digits.DEL.. the numbers which I have given is for sample. I need .dat file should have exactly 11 digits after the last underscore and other two files should have only 7 digits after the last underscore

Comment: There are a lot of different versions of ksh, and a bunch of shells *not* made by David Korn (usually slower than and incompatible with the real deal) that still call themselves ksh. mksh, pdksh, ksh87, ksh93 -- they all have different subsets of features. It's helpful to be more specific than just saying "ksh": Which specific shell are you *actually* using?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic wildcard generation method.  Print the filenames with leading text and line numbers...

1. POSIX shell:

   ```
   2> /dev/null  find \ 
     $(echo Ad_sf_03041500000.dat SF_AD_0304150.DEL SF_AD_0404141.EXP |
       sed 's/[0-9]/[0-9]/g' ) | 
   while read f ; do
       echo "Here's $f"; 
   done | nl
   ```
2. `ksh` (with a spot borrowed from [*Chepner*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509639/ksh-shell-script-matching-file-pattern/46532227?noredirect=1#comment80020493_46532227)):

   ```
   set - Ad_sf_03041500000.dat SF_AD_0304150.DEL SF_AD_0404141.EXP
   for f in ${*//[0-9]/[0-9]} ; do [ -f "$f" ] || continue
       echo "Here's $f"; 
   done | nl
   ```

Output of either method:

```
     1  Here's Ad_sf_03041500000.dat
     2  Here's SF_AD_0304150.DEL
     3  Here's SF_AD_0404141.EXP
```

If the line numbers aren't wanted, omit the `| nl`.  `echo` can be replaced with whatever command needs to be run on the files.

---

How the POSIX code works.  The OP spec is simple enough to churn out the correct wildcard with a little tweaking.  Example:

```
echo Ad_sf_03041500000.dat SF_AD_0304150.DEL SF_AD_0404141.EXP | 
sed 's/[0-9]/[0-9]/g'
```

Which outputs exactly the patterns needed (line feeds added for clarity):

```
Ad_sf_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].dat
SF_AD_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].DEL 
SF_AD_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].EXP
```

The patterns above go to `find`, which prints only the matching filenames, (not the pattern itself when there are no files), then the filenames go to a `while` loop.

(The `ksh` variant is the same method but uses *pattern substitution*, `set`, and `test -f` in place of `sed` and `find`.)

Comment: Most likely the OP means a more abstract pattern, but a fixed string is also a pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your support my friend @agc. I guess you wrongly understood my question. my file pattern is ad_sf_11digits.dat and SF_AD_7digits.EXP and SF_AD_7digits.DEL.. the numbers which I have given is for sample. I need .dat file should have exactly 11 digits after the last underscore and other two files should have only 7 digits after the last underscore

Answer (score 1):

The patterns you are looking for are

```
Ad_sf_{11}([[:digit:]]).dat
SF_AD_{7}([[:digit:]]).DEL
SF_AD_{7}([[:digit:]]).EXP
```

Note that the `{n}(...)` pattern, to match exactly `n` occurrences of the following pattern, is an extension unique to `ksh` (as far as I know, not even `zsh` provides an equivalent).

To iterate over matching files, you can use

```
for f in Ad_sf_{11}(\d).dat SF_AD_{7}(\d).@(DEL|EXP); do
```

where I've use the "pick one" operator `@(...)` to combine the two shorter patterns into a single pattern, and I've used `\d`, which `ksh` supports as a shorter version of `[[:digit:]]` when inside parentheses.

Comment: *Lubuntu v17.04*, tested the above code in `mksh`, returns:  `syntax error: '(' unexpected`.  Tested in `ksh`, an `echo $f` in the loop prints the patterns themselves when the files don't exist -- possibly that's desired, but it might not be...

Comment: `mksh` is "largely compatible with ksh", but it is not `ksh`, which is what the OP claims to be using. As for what happens when no match occurs, that is clearly documented in the man page under Filename Generation: "If no file name is found that matches the pattern, then that component of the filename is
       left unchanged unless the pattern is prefixed with ~(N) in which case it is removed  as  described  below."

Comment: The standard approach is to check if `f` is actually a file at the top of the loop: `[ -f "$f" ] || continue`.